# JSP affecting checbox variable using database

Tags: html, oracle, jsp

So i'm trying to get from the database values to display. Currently, i can get any text values but i cannot get the checkboxes to work and i don't understand why. Using the following code

```
<td>Street: <input type="text" name="Address1" value="<% out.print(MyProperties.getString(3)); %>" disabled="true"></td>
<td>No. of Bedrooms: <input type="text" name="Bedrooms" value="<% out.print(MyProperties.getString(9)); %>" disabled="true"></td>
<td>Garden: <input type="checkbox" name="Garden" disabled="true" <% if(MyProperties.getString(10) == "1"){ out.print("checked='checked'");} %>></td>
```

This will draw out values as text for "address1" and "bedrooms" but i cannot get the checkbox for garden to work.

In the database, i have text values for the first two working variables, and the value for the checkbox is either text(string) or int (sorry, i can't remember exactly and i need to check it) but what i've written doesn't work for either `getString(9) == "1" or getInt(9) == 1`

However i can take the value from the database and print it out using the line

```
<td><% out.print(MyProperties.getString(10)); %></td>
```

does work.

Keep in mind that both of my tables are within a while loop

```
<% while (MyProperties.next()){ %> TABLE <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<%=MyProperties.getInt(10) == 1?"checked":""%>
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: With the addition of "MyProperties." (and correcting the number in getInt from 9 to 10 as i initially put it wrong) it works. Now i need to know ... why? What's actually different in your code to mine?

Comment: you are not marking the check box checked. for jsp you value means nothing unless it is "checked" string. clearly you have value 1 that is why it not checking the checkbox